# Do I need a transit visa if I have 4 hours of stopover in Jeddah?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I have a stopover in Jeddah and then I have to move to Mumbai. My stopover is about 4 hours and a half. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Is it a single ticket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a transit visa for Saudi Arabia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114508/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-saudi-arabia)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am transiting through Saudi Arabia. Do I need a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185294/i-am-transiting-through-saudi-arabia-do-i-need-a-visa)