# I am transiting through Saudi Arabia. Do I need a visa?

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia, self-transfer, ruh, riyadh

I am transiting through Saudi Arabia via the airport at Riyadh (RUH), Jeddah (JED), or Dammam (DMM). Do I need a visa for this?

Comment: Note: this is a canonical question. Please mark any other questions on transiting via Saudi Arabia by plane as duplicates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whether you need a visa or not depends on many factors. In order from top to bottom:

### If you are a citizen of a Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) country

Citizens of Bahrain, Kuwait, Oman, Qatar and the United Arab Emirates do not need a visa for Saudi Arabia.

### If you have a single ticket from the same airline, with a connection under 12 hours at the same airport

**You do not need a visa**, regardless of nationality. You will not be allowed to leave the transit zone in the airport.

Warning: a "self-transfer" booked through Kiwi.com or its competitors is *not considered a single ticket*, and you will likely need a visa!

### If you have a connection of over 12 hours at the same airport, and are flying Saudia or Flynas only

You are eligible for the [free 96-hour transit visa](https://www.saudi-visa.org/new-transit-visa-for-saudi-arabia-launched#:%7E:text=Introducing%20the%20New%20Saudi%20Arabia%20Transit%20Visa&text=The%20Ministry%20of%20Foreign%20Affairs,96%20hours%20in%20the%20Kingdom.), regardless of nationality. The visa application must be made at the same time as your flight booking:

- Saudia: [Stopover Visa](https://www.saudia.com/transit-visa)
- Flynas: [Transit/Stopover Visa](https://www.flynas.com/en/stopovervisa)

For Saudia only, you *may* be eligible for one free hotel night as well; see details at the link above.

### If you are a national of an [eligible country](https://visa.visitsaudi.com/)

You qualify for a tourist visa. You can apply online in advance at the link above (SAR 480), or receive a visa on arrival (SAR 535).

You can also opt to apply for a transit visa, which is slightly cheaper; see below.

### If you hold permanent residence in the US, the UK or the EU; or you have a *previously used* US, UK, or Schengen visa

You can apply for an eVisa or visa on arrival, see above.

The PR/visa must be a currently valid tourism or business visa, and *must have already been used at least once*. For example, if you are traveling via Saudi to the EU for the first time, you do not qualify for the Saudi on-arrival visa on the way *to* Europe, but you do qualify on the way back *from* Europe.

### If you are a resident of a GCC country

You can apply for an eVisa, see above. You are *not* eligible for a visa on arrival.

Your GCC resident permit must be valid for at least three months, and your passport valid for six months at least.

### If none of these conditions apply

You must apply for a [regular Saudi transit visa](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474/!ut/p/z0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivQIsTAwdDQz9LQwNzQwCnS0tXPwMvYwN3A30g1Pz9L30o_ArAppiVOTr7JuuH1WQWJKhm5mXlq8fYWFibqJfkO0eDgDtRK6y/) (or similar).  The cost is 300 SAR.

*This is a community-owned canonical answer to this frequently asked question. If it's inaccurate or incomplete, please edit it!*

Comment: Does a Schengen temporary resident permit work as well?

Comment: Not sure how to handle the case of flights on the same ticket connecting via Riyadh using terminals without airside transit…

Comment: "If you have a single ticket from the same airline, with a connection under 12 hours. You will not be allowed to leave the transit zone in the airport." 1) If one has 2 tickets and a connection of less than 12 hours, can one use a regular Saudi transit visa to enter Saudi Arabia? 2) If one has a tourist visa and a connection of less than 12 hours, can one enter Saudi Arabia?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Of course you can enter *if you have a visa*.

Comment: @lambshaanxy sorry for not being explicit, but the two questions implied: can we get a visa in that case?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's been many years, but IIRC the Saudi visa application doesn't even ask about your flights.